# how to prevent content scrolling behind footer in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, css, web-applications, ionic-framework

My app is built using ionic framework (http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/).

Do you know how to prevent scrolling page content to not scroll behind the footer?
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#footer

This is currently resulting in content I cannot see. I'd rather have the scrolling region's boundary end at the top of the footer (rather than the bottom of the screen). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the padding utility class to add some breathing room at the bottom of the content area.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the `ion-footer-bar` on your abstract template (your router config will have a a value 'abstract') you can apply `has-footer` to your `ion-content` (or use it on `ion-view` too, I think)

Comment: …or on `ion-nav-view`. **Unless** you have both header and footer, in which case it really should be applied to `ion-content` (as `has-header` gets automatically added to `ion-content` while `has-footer` does not — this might be a bug on my side, though)

Comment: this has never been a feature in ionic framework